Is Apple's 'False Bottom' design enhancing engagement or causing frustration?
Apple's website has a 'false bottom' design, where users might think they've reached the end of a page, but scrolling reveals more content. Do you think this approach enhances user engagement, or could it lead to frustration? Another example is Cred website.
Are these design choices ever intentional? If so, what are the rationales behind such apparent usability pitfalls?
https://cxl.com/blog/false-bottom/

